# Container Port Not Exposed in Kubernetes

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to connect a Postgres pod with my Django app pod but somehow my Django app pod port is not exposed. In my app's `Dockerfile` I added `EXPOSE 8000`, however when I ssh into my pod I cannot serve my app (returns an error asking if a postgres server is up and running on port 5432 and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432) and when run `nmap` I get this

```
root@app-kbqd8:~/app# nmap 12.3.4.567

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-06 15:24 UTC
Nmap scan report for postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local (12.3.4.567)
Host is up (0.00063s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.171) are filtered
```

My app's service is:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: myapp
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
```

For my postgres pod

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: user/postgres
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
```

and its service

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    component: postgres
    role: master
    name: postgres
```

Comment: In the container you should have the process running. Your problem might be that you bound your postgres to an interface?

Comment: Well when I run `ps aux`, I can see postgres running along with chepointer, writer, autovacuum, and stats colelctor process. Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Internally in postgresql there is interface binding as security out of the box. Google on that (gets you this article https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B79CCFE.5040105@hogranch.com). Check that and it relatives to see if you postgresql is even accessible.

Comment: Also, running 'ss -tnlpe' inside the container's namespace will show which interface and port postgres is listening on.